# Wrapper function which calls another function with the arguments passed in a rotated order

Tags: c++

How to write a function template which calls a function, but with the parameters passed in rotated manner: the last parameter should become as the first one for the called function?

This does the job, but `PARAMETERS` cannot be deduced:

```cpp
template <typename ...PARAMETERS, typename LAST, typename FN>
void call_rotated(FN fn, PARAMETERS &&...parameters, LAST &&last) {
    fn(std::forward<LAST>(last), std::forward<PARAMETERS>(parameters)...);
}
```

In the next example, calling `call_rotated(print, 1, 2, "was_last")` calls the `print` function with parameters `("was_last", 1, 2)`, so it prints "was_last 1 2":

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <cstdio>

template <typename ...PARAMETERS, typename LAST, typename FN>
void call_rotated(FN fn, PARAMETERS &&...parameters, LAST &&last) {
    fn(std::forward<LAST>(last), std::forward<PARAMETERS>(parameters)...);
}

void print(const char *l, int a, int b) {
    printf("%s %d %d\n", l, a, b);
}

int main() {
    call_rotated<int, int>(&print, 1, 2, "was_last");
}
```

But the problem is that I had to specify the template parameters `<int, int>` to `call_rotated`. Is it possible to write `call_rotated` in a way that deduction works for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), you might do:

```
template <typename FN, typename ...Ts>
void call_rotated(FN fn, Ts&&...parameters)
{
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        return fn(std::get<(sizeof...(Is) - 1 + Is) % sizeof...(Is)>(
            std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(parameters)...))...);
    }(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>());
}
```

Above code need C++20, but might be adapted for older standard.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xx6jexzc7)